# Почему в бесконечном цикле при отмене ввода, цикл все равно продолжает работать?

Tags: javascript

Есть такое задание: Напишите цикл, который предлагает prompt ввести число, большее 100. Если посетитель ввёл другое число – попросить ввести ещё раз, и так далее.

Цикл должен спрашивать число пока либо посетитель не введёт число, большее 100, либо не нажмёт кнопку Отмена (ESC).

Я написал такой код

```
outer: while (true) {
  let value = +prompt('Введите число больше 100?', 0);
  
  if (value < 100) {
    continue outer;
  } else if (!value || value > 100) {
    break outer;
  }
}
```

Почему при отмене все равно выводится промт?

Comment: не правда. всё работает как надо (если число больше 100), а при отмене будет 0, что меньше 100

Comment: Потому что при отмене ты получаешь `0` который очевидно меньше `100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замечания:

- Не очень понятно зачем метки на первом уровне цикла? Его обычно используют чтобы продолжить/остановить цикл, который вне цикла, где используется данная команда
- При отмене приходит `null`, который превращатся в `0`, потому срабатывает `value < 100`
- На `null` надо проверять до приведения к числу, так вы сможете отличить 0 и `null`
- Если ввести строку, которая не переводится в число, например `'qwe'`, то он вместо числа запишет `NaN`, потому проверку на него тоже надо делать
- Писать `else` после `break/continue`, в цикле, так же бессмыслленно как в функциях писать `else` после `return`-а, потому его можно убрать

Учитывая замечания, ваш код можно написать так:

```js
while (true) {
  const value = prompt('Введите число больше 100?', 0);
  
  if (value === null) break;
  
  const valueAsNum = Number(value);
  
  if (isNaN(valueAsNum) || valueAsNum > 100) break;
  
  if (valueAsNum < 100) continue; //Эту строку можно убрать, если нет дополнительной логики
}
```

Comment: _Если число будет равным 0, то вы его пропустите дальше, потому что !0_ - не пропустит, потому что `< 100` проверяется раньше

Comment: _if (valueAsNum < 100) continue;_ - эта строка вообще не нужна

Comment: @Grundy На счёт первого да точно, я просто для себя эксперементировал и у меня это условие было первым, забыл потом код автора глянуть, щас поправлю) На счёт второго я специально оставил, вдруг ещё условия будут или что-то другое

Comment: Э-э-э, `isNaN(valueAsNum)` по логике должно быть условием продолжения цикла, а не прерывания.

Comment: @PavelMayorov У автора было написано чтобы при `!value` был `break`, а `NaN` кандидат на выполнение этого условия) Потому и написал чтобы был `break`

Answer (score 3):

При нажатии кнопки отмена `prompt` возвращает `null`, который при приведении к числу превращается в `0`.

таким образом, выбирается вариант `value < 100` и цикл не заканчивается.

Проверять на `null` стоит до приведения к числу:

```
outer: while (true) {
  let value = prompt('Введите число больше 100?', 0);
  
  if (value == null)  break outer;

  value = +value;
  if (value < 100) {
    continue outer;
  } else if (!value || value > 100) {
    break outer;
  }
}
```